How To find duplicate entries on 3 columns and group them together
I have a DB table "TRANS" with multiple rows in. But some of the rows have certain columns that contain duplicate entries and I'm trying to create a select query to show me the data that is duplicated.
AUTHIDRESP  REQAMT  ADDRESS_NAME    HPAN MSG_TYPE TRANS_TYPE
123456      88.70    London         1    1         3
874567      4.78     Paris          23   1         3
456274      1.65     Paris          3    1         3
112356      88.70    London         1    1         3
887456      1.65     Paris          3    2         3 
114568      4.78     Paris          23   2         3

I'd like the select query to show the output where the Amount and Name and HPAN match but also display the AUTHID as this will be a unique value and group them together by 'HPAN' so you can see each entry more easily
So the output would be in order like this:
AUTHIDRESP  REQAMT  ADDRESS_NAME    HPAN MSG_TYPE TRANS_TYPE
123456      88.70   London           1    1        3
112356      88.70   London           1    1        3
887456       1.65   Paris            3    1        3
456274       1.65   Paris            3    2        3
114568       4.78   Paris            23   1        3
874567       4.78   Paris            23   2        3

I have tried this query but it is not giving me the output I need as it appears to just give a long list of everything.
select AUTHIDRESP, HPAN, MSGTYPE, REQAMT, TRANS_TYPE, ADDRESS_NAME
from TRANS s
where 
1 < (select count(*) from TRANS i where i.HPAN = s.HPAN and i.REQAMT = s.REQAMT and i.ADDRESS_NAME = s.ADDRESS_NAME and i.TRANS_TYPE = s.TRANS_TYPE) 
and date = '20240815' 

Any help would be much appreciated thanks

Do you simply want an ORDER BY? (Looks like you want the same rows and same values, just a different order.)

Add ORDER BY ADDRESS_NAME, HPAN, REQAMT at the end, and see if it gives you the desired result.

Yes, there are other rows with other data in the table and I don't want those to show up in my query . I think that has sorted it thanks

You should have included such rows in you sample data, to make the problem much clearer.

You can simply use with With Duplicates to find duplicates.
I have provided a link that I used to test the result using dbfiddle
Here is the link: dbfiddble
Here is the code to guide you
WITH DuplicateRows AS (
    SELECT
        HPAN,
        REQAMT,
        ADDRESS_NAME,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
        TRANS
    WHERE
        date = '20240815'
    GROUP BY
        HPAN,
        REQAMT,
        ADDRESS_NAME
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT
    t.AUTHIDRESP,
    t.REQAMT,
    t.ADDRESS_NAME,
    t.HPAN,
    t.MSG_TYPE,
    t.TRANS_TYPE
FROM
    TRANS t
JOIN
    DuplicateRows d
ON
    t.HPAN = d.HPAN
    AND t.REQAMT = d.REQAMT
    AND t.ADDRESS_NAME = d.ADDRESS_NAME
WHERE
    t.date = '20240815'
ORDER BY
    t.HPAN,
    t.REQAMT,
    t.ADDRESS_NAME;


If you just want so see rows for which duplicates exist and hide the others then you can use the ROW_NUMBER() analytical function . I added a row with no dupe to the sample data, it's not shown in the results.
WITH t (authidresp,reqamt,address_name,hpan,msg_type,trans_type) AS
(
SELECT 123456,  88.70 ,'London',   1 , 1 ,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 874567,  4.78  ,'Paris',   23, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456274,  1.65  ,'Paris', 3 , 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112356,  88.70 ,'London',   1 , 1 ,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 887456,  1.65  ,'Paris', 3 , 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 89887,  1.65  ,'Brussels', 3 , 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 114568,  4.78  ,'Paris',   23, 2, 3 FROM DUAL
), all_rows_w_rn AS
(
SELECT authidresp
      ,reqamt
      ,address_name
      ,hpan
      ,msg_type
      ,trans_type
      ,ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY reqamt
                         ,address_name
                         ,hpan
             ORDER BY address_name
        ) as rn
  FROM t
), dupe_rows AS 
(
SELECT reqamt
      ,address_name
      ,hpan
  FROM all_rows_w_rn
 WHERE rn = 2
)
SELECT t.*
  FROM t t
  JOIN dupe_rows d ON t.address_name = d.address_name AND
                      t.hpan = d.hpan AND
                      t.reqamt = d.reqamt
  ORDER BY t.address_name,  t.reqamt , t.hpan;



Use COUNT() window function to find duplicates, partition by hpan, reqamt, address_name.
select authidresp, reqamt, address_name, hpan, msg_type, trans_type
from
(
  select t.*,
         count(*) over (partition by hpan, reqamt, address_name) cnt 
  FROM trans t
) dt
where cnt > 1
ORDER BY address_name, hpan, reqamt;

Demo at: https://dbfiddle.uk/XPttvf1R
